# Count of the result of a MongoDB aggregate query with lookup and match

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have two collections:   **job,mobile** 
job -->  **_id,title,personid** 
mobile -->  **_id,mobileNumber,personId** 
fields are **string.**

two collections relationship: **personid**

get **count** of **job** collection:
db.job.count({title :"programmer"}); --> result:  76522

my problem is here:

```js
db.job.aggregate([
  {$group : {_id:{title:"$title",personid:"$personid"},count:{$sum:1}}},
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "mobile",
          localField: "_id.personid",
          foreignField: "personId",
          as: "mobileDocs"
        }
   },
   {
      $match:{ 
          title: "programmer",
          "mobileDocs.mobileNumber": /^9352/
          }}
]);
```

i want **count of result** for example count(number) of mobile or title :

5200

very **fast** and **work with $lookup and $match**

Comment: What's the issue? Is the result slow or wrong? Can you use the `$match` as the 1st step of your pipeline. Also, that `$regex` should have been a `$eq`

Comment: Do you really need to have two collections? Why don't you just put the mobile number directly in the job collection ? The query would be way faster...

Comment: thank you for your comment. but i want two collections together.that is my business and with big data inside them